# Python - Can't see what I'm typing, grey background

Tags: python, text, background

Just downloaded Python, but can't see what I'm typing. Have tried to uninstall and reinstall bt there is obviously something wrong. Can anyone help me out here?

[grey background, can't see what I'm typing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47YZZ.png)

Comment: Is it not responding? Is that Idle?

Comment: How about open the command line first, then run `python`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's working properly and the background is the issue, try the following:

1. Right click on the titlebar and click on properties:
   [image]
2. Go to colors and change the screen background colour (right now it looks grey, so pick a different colour like black, the first one in the picture below):

   [image]